# How to add custom webpack config with ionic v4 and react?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic4

I have set up a project using ionic framework v4 with React and wish to add a webpack loader to allow importing graphql queries from `.graphql` files, as described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/integrations/webpack/).

I can't find any official documentation on how to change anything relating to webpack (for example, nothing [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration)), and existing answers on the subject seem to apply only to using Angular or v2/v3 of ionic.

The Apollo docs describe an alternative way of solving this for Create-React-App (which I may try as a workaround), but I might wish to change webpack config in other ways, so I am also asking how to solve this question more generally.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize webpack using [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired)

#### If you don't use ionic cli to build and run your app, you can use a normal install of react-app-rewired.

### If you use the ionic cli, there is an additional step/trick:

Ionic uses react-scripts under the hood, so you need to trick it into using react-app-rewired instead of react-scripts.

Here is a simple and low-invasive way to have Ionic cli use react-app-rewired instead of react-scripts: add this package.json `postinstall` script:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd node_modules/.bin && mv react-scripts react-scripts-real && ln -s ../react-app-rewired/bin/index.js react-scripts",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @bdombro, I've been on holiday from project where this came up, but will try this out when I get a chance.

Comment: @contrebis, did this ever work? Is webpack really customizable in ionic?

Comment: Hi @RichardDomingo, unfortunately I never got to try this, and a coworker took over this project so I'm not actively working on it any more. I did a quick search shows some people attempting solutions, and the ionic issue log doesn't seem to have any questions/issues on this topic...

Comment: I was able to try this. It worked. I was able to use customize-cra. However, I didn't succeed with what I wanted to do. I tried to add a loader for ".md" file (mdx-loader). But I'm not sure why, the file never got read. I didnt pursue it. I moved on now. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: save my day, bro !

Comment: This worked for me. Does feel a bit hacky, but as the ionic cli doesn't seem to support a configuration for the build command then I guess this is the best option short of forking the cli project.

Comment: If anyone is interested -- I am using Ionic + Vite with success lately by using the Ionic "custom" config. Can share instructions.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This fails when you run `ionic build` because it defaults back to using `react-scripts build`.

Not sure why I didn't see this before, but taking a closer look at the bootstrapped ionic project, it’s clearly using create-react-app/react-scripts.

Although CRA demands you do a one-time eject in order to configure anything relating to the build, I was able to use `react-app-rewired` and `customizable-cra` to customise the build and start scripts. As far as I can tell this works fine with ionic.

Comment: Hey, past me, is this a good solution or not? Why did I select it as the answer if it doesn't work properly?